# Materialize dropdown don't working inside div with "display: none"

Tags: jquery, materialize

If the "Dropdown" is inside a hidden div, and then placed in a visible div, this "Dropdown" does not work.

The first "drop down" works!
But by pressing "Add other Dropdown" will appear a new "Dropdown", but this no longer works, why?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Dropdown</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown2'>Drop Me!</a>
     <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
     <ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
     </ul>
    
     <hr><hr>
    
     <button class="puthere">Add other Dropdown</button>
    
     <hr><hr>
    
     <div id="drophere"></div>
    
     <div id="repository" style="display: none;">
      <div class="exemple">
       <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
       <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
       <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
       <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
        <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".puthere").on("click", puthere);
    
       function puthere() {
        let $clone = $("#repository .exemple").clone(true);
        $clone.appendTo($("#drophere"));
       }
      });
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: very simple start point is ID's can't be repeated in a page...also you will probably have to manually initialize drop-down script on it

Comment: but ID's are not repeated. one ID is "dropdown1" e another ID is "dropdown2".

Comment: how can that be when you clone the  existing one and don't modify it?

Comment: exact, you're right! but how do I change the "ID" in the clone?